# I can't insert files from my Google Drive on my website

Tags: cloud, drive

I have image and video files stored in Google Drive that I inserted into my website through this code:

[https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={File](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=%7BFile) ID}

But it hasn't been working for a few days now.

I am trying to find the new code to insert Google Drive files on my website. Does anyone know the new code?

Comment: May find useful answers in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367610/showing-documents-from-google-drive-on-webpage

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround, don't know for how long it will work though.
Best option is to host images elsewhere as google services are unreliable, and
when you have an issue, who you gonna call ghostbusters?

```html
    <body>
      <!-- Thumbnail link with a larger width -->
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome&sz=w1000" alt="Your Image Alt Text">
    
      <!-- Thumbnail link without width -->
      <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1BEW9tkgVKlp_ebUc17LkXDH-mnPc4ome" alt="Your Image Alt Text">
    </body>
```

[Source](https://codepen.io/raulpenate/pen/wvOozzw)

Comment: Thanks it works for me. What happens is that I also have a short video and it doesn't go here. Only works for images